# Creating an alias for Python in bash/zsh

Tags: terminal, bash, python, zsh, alias

I have often seen people recommending to setup an alias in one's `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` along the lines of

```
alias python='python3'
```

This seems like a convenient idea, however, as far as I understand, python2 is still installed for compatibility reasons, so won't creating such an alias break certain things?

Comment: What do you mean by breaking things?

Comment: Some other script using python and relying on some pre python3 syntax.

Comment: If a python2 script is called in the shell by the command `python`, then yes, something might break. The question is whether you have any scripts that use that method, rather than explicitly stating `/usr/bin/python` or `python2`.

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`

```
Aliases  are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the
expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description  of
shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).
```

So unless you explicitly set an option, aliases aren't expanded in scripts and any reference to `python` will call the binary directly. For interactive use it's probably best to call `python2` directly if you rely on pre-3 syntax/functionality.

PS: AFAIK it's the same for `zsh`.